# Is there a list of popular surnames organised by region/prefecture?

Tags: resources

I've seen a lot of 'Top 100 Japanese surnames' sorts of lists, but obviously some names are much more popular in some regions than others. Is there a resource (preferably in Japanese!) that would take this into account?

Answer (score 6):

- [都道{とどう}府県{ふけん}別{べつ}名字{みょうじ}ランキング](http://home.r01.itscom.net/morioka/myoji/best20.html) - a top 20 surname list of each prefecture published by Hiroshi Morioka, a Japanese surname researcher
- [同姓{どうせい}同名{どうめい}辞典{じてん}](http://www.douseidoumei.net/) - huge rankings of Japanese names generated from telephone directories

Answer (score 2):

A telephone directory of that region will give a good approximation.